# Why does $\int_\pi^\infty \frac{2+\cos x} {x}\, \mathrm dx$ diverge

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_\pi^\infty \frac{2+\cos x} {x}\, \mathrm dx,$$
$$0<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{2+\cos x}{x},$$ for $x\geq \pi$.

Can someone explain to me how to this is proved? And what makes the integral diverge? Thank you.

Comment: If you know that $\int_\pi^{+\infty}1/x\,dx$ diverges and you have the inequality you mention, then use the comparison theorem. It is not clear to me what is your problem.

Comment: @mickep can you explain to me how to get this condition $0<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{2+\cos x}{x},$ for $x\geq \pi$?

Comment: @fiksx $\cos x\geq -1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @uniquesolution $\cos x\geq -1$ because it is related to $x\geq \pi$?

Comment: The $\pi$ could be changed to any other positive constant. So it does not really play a role here.

Comment: @fiksx $\cos x\geq -1$ because that's how the cosine is.

Comment: @uniquesolution from this  $\cos x\geq -1$, we divide by $x$ and +2 to get $0<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{2+\cos x}{x}$? and also   is $sinx \geq -1$ too ?

Comment: @fiksx  Seriously. If you don't know that $\sin x\geq -1$ you should study elementary trigonometry first, and only then discuss convergence of improper integrals involving trigonometric functions.

Comment: @uniquesolution i know that $\cos x\geq -1$  for all x, but since the integral is from $\pi$ to $\infty$ and $cos \pi =-1$ so i can use this $\cos x\geq -1$? in other words it is depend on the range(?)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\int_\pi^\infty \frac{2+\cos x}{x}dx\ge \int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx=\infty$$

Comment: thankyou!!! but can you explain to me how can i get this? $0<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{2+\cos x}{x},$ for $x\geq \pi$

Comment: @fiksx, just observe that $1+\cos x\ge 0$.

Comment: okay thanks!! but is there any relation with $x\geq \pi$ ? and then i divide by x so i will get this $0<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{2+\cos x}{x},$?

Comment: Only $x>0$ will suffice.

Comment: @samratmukhopadyay sorry i dont understand, can you elaborate more?

Comment: Basically, we need $cos x\in [-1,1]$, along with $x>0$, to get $(1+\cos x)/x>0$, which implies $(2+\cos x)/x>1/x>0$

Comment: @samratmukhopadyay ok but how do you know that $x>0$ suffice? is this related to $x \geq \pi$? but $cos \pi =-1$ so why $x>0$

Comment: @fiksx,x>0,1/x>0,1+$\cos x>0,2+\cos x>1,so:(2+\cos x)/x>1/x>0$